# Integrate : $\int (1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots )dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate this :

$\int (1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots )dx $

My approach :

$\int (1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots )dx $
=$x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots $

Is this series = $(1-x)^{-1}$

Please suggest, will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: Except for the $+C$ this is correct.

Comment: **Formally**, yes that is the integral. For the second question, try computing $(1-x)(x+x^2+x^3+\dots)$.

Comment: You forgot term x .

Comment: i have a question $$\frac{(1-x)}{1-x}(x+x^2+x^3+......)$$ is equal to$$\frac{x-x^N}{1-x}$$ with $\lim_{N\to\infty}$. is that true?

Answer (score 4):

You should assume that $-1 <x <1$

and the result is

$$C+x+x^2+x^3+...=\color {red}{x}\frac {1}{1-x} +C$$

$$=\frac {1}{1-x}+D $$

Comment: $$\frac{x}{1-x} + C = -1 + \frac{1}{1-x} + C = \frac{1}{1-x} + C'.$$  Consequently, the additional $x$ is not required.

Comment: @heropup yes in fact. good remark (+1).

Comment: @yeah, for indifinite integral, it may not matter but for a definite integral it may make a difference

Answer (score 1):

$$\int(1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\dots)dx = \int \left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}ix^{i-1}\right)= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int ix^{i-1}dx = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i\frac{x^i}{i} +c=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x^i+c=\frac{x}{1-x}+c$$

Comment: $+C\phantom{}$.